# Bootstrap : adding img-responsive class to thumbnail

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have to add img-responsive class to  an image in wordpress  page template. 
My file is  named as single-product.php.

This is my code

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:35px;">
    <h1><?php the_title();?></h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
   <?php  the_post_thumbnail();?>
 </div>
```

Now my question is how to add class to thumbnail?

Please assist me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the class name in the_thumbnail function .

```
 <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'your-class-name')); ?>
```

For More Refrence
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Comment: can i also pass style='' in array ?

Answer (score 2):

the_post_thumbnail() takes two arguments, size and an array of attributes. one of the attributes you can set in the array is class, so an example would look like this

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
```

you may want to change thumbnail to the size you would like, or perhaps you can leave it blank. as always search the codex for the function in question and it normally has the answers https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail

Answer (score 2):

Like this,

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive' ) ); ?>
```

Also, it is not a good practice to use inline styles in your code.